# Despite using await, the UI thread still blocks

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I perform a bunch of operations one after the other.

The basic structure is

Form's `Run()` method > calls `Manager.DoStuff()` using `await Manager.DoStuff();`

`Manager.DoStuff()` is `async Task ...`

Therefore I'd never expect it to block the UI thread, and it doesn't for most things: The `DoStuff` method contains stuff like:

```
var someTask = Something.BigTask();
var someTask2 = Something2.BigTask();
var someTask3 = Something3.BigTask();
```

`await Task.WhenAll(someTask, someTask2, someTask3)`

and some individual ones, eg:

`await SomethingElse.BigTask();`

but when it gets to a certain one the UI thread jams up and I eventually get an exception saying it's not pumping messages.

The method is no different, it's an `async Task SomeMethod()`

The only thing I can think of is that it uses `Invoke` on the form to log a lot of messages. Could this affect it? If so I need to figure out how to stop that from breaking it.

Presumably if you're doing `await` on an async Task from the UI thread, nothing within that async task should block the UI thread?

After the highest level call to `await` there is no more code, the initial Run() method simply ends as that is the last task it has to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Form class?  What `Run()` method?  Post completer code and indicate which GUI.

Comment: It's a windows form app, and there is a button that calls a method called `Run()`

Comment: Does the awaited method actually do anything async, or just hefty sync work?

Comment: It does a lot of hefty synchronous work, except for the logging which uses the `Invoke` method on the form (which I guess is sort of cross-thread asynchronous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find that until you do work that is actually async (usually IO) rather than blocking work with no async IO, the calls will be performed synchronously. Consider `Task.Run` to run in the ThreadPool or even `Task.Factory.StartNew(theCall, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)`... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321263.aspx

Comment: [Using `StartNew` this way is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), as I explain on my blog. The safe overload for `StartNew` is `Task.Factory.StartNew(theCall, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default)`, and that's a lot more wordy than just using `Task.Run(theCall)`.

Comment: In my case the thing that is blocking the UI thread is a while loop that updates the progress bar. If I put that in its own Task, the progress bar doesn't get updated.